# How come one of my images aren't displaying next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line up 3 images and some text on one 'line', the first 2 images are lined up fine, same with the text but the 3rd image refuses to and i'm not sure why.

here is my code so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

.pfp {
  display: inline;
}

.msg {
  display: inline;
}

.userid {
  text-decoration-color: white;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>
  <img src='logo.jpg' , width=1 00px>
</div>

<div class="pfp">
  <a href="Profile Page.html">
    <img src='pfp.jpg' , width=5 0px>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='userid'>
  <span>[user_id]</span>
</div>
<div class='msg'>
  <a href='messages.html'>
    <img src='messages.jpg' , width=5 0px>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the image of the output which you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.userid` also needs to be displayed inline or inline-block so the next item can be inline with it. Right now it's displayed as block so it's shoving anything after it to the next line.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

.pfp {
  display: inline;
}

.msg {
  display: inline;
}

.userid {
  text-decoration-color: white;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  text-align: left;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  //display: block;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class='logo'>
  <img src='logo.jpg' , width=1 00px>
</div>

<div class="pfp">
  <a href="Profile Page.html">
    <img src='pfp.jpg' , width=5 0px>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='userid'>
  <span>[user_id]</span>
</div>
<div class='msg'>
  <a href='messages.html'>
    <img src='messages.jpg' , width=5 0px>
  </a>
</div>
```